# None type object has no attribute get

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

```
#Global Variable
context_data = None # contains dictionary

@api.multi
def custom_code(self):
    # code to generate dictionary
    context_data = my_dict
    res = self.env['ir.model.data'].get_object_reference('moduleA', 'dash_form_view')

    return {
         'view_type': 'form',
         'view_mode': 'form',
         'view_id': res[1],
         'res_model': 'report.sales.dash',
         'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
         'target': 'current',
         'context': g_data
         }    

@api.model
def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', toolbar=False, submenu=False):
     res = super(sales_dash_report, self).fields_view_get(
     view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)

    # Global variable 
    global context_data

    if view_type == 'form' and context_data.get('key'):
        #some code to execute
    return res
```

While execute on local machine it executing normal but while try to run on production server then it gives an error that context_data (None object) has no attribute get.

Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: As you return `'context': g_data` in your method. But I can not find `g_data` declaration or assign any dictionary. Please update your relevant code.

Comment: `context_data = None` and what are you expecting?

Comment: hi, @DachiDarchiashvili   In method custom_code() I assign dictionary to the context_copy so I will create dynamic fields when view loads, by fields_view_get()

Comment: hi @Odedra, The g_data is nothing just a dictionary I am sending to the view to load data by default while load the form view.

Comment: I having the Issue with the global variable context_data that while I assign the dictionary to the code that is not available in fields_view_get method, The code is working fine while test locally but it giving error on the client server

Comment: Thanks for support guys, I got to know that the issue is of some bus service, as it transferring data slow that generating this issue and giving me an error.